# How do I pass a filename as a parameter to a batch file running mysql statements?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, forfiles

I have a batch script that needs to process the latest CSV file in a folder. The filename changes everyday. How do I pass the filename as a parameter to a set of MYSQL commands.

This is what I have so far:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\mydir\*.csv" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I

"mysql.exe" -u USER -pPASS schema < c:\mydir\sql_stmts.txt
```

In that "sql_stmts.txt" file I have this command, among others:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/mydir/<<FILENAME>>' INTO TABLE my_staging_table
```

So, how do I pass the "NewestFile" parameter to that sql_stmts.txt command to be used in the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" statement?

Comment: So basically you want to modify the `*.txt` file, right?

Comment: @aschipfl yes, correct.